# How to select all itemclass in acumatica

Tags: c#, acumatica

Hello i want to select all of the itemclassid from a data class and i want to iterate through them can someone teach me how to start with it. i know how to select a row but i do not know how to select all then iterate through them

```
    foreach (INItemclass items in ???)
{

}
```

[image]
i want to get them individaully because i want to update each of them and put a specific value through each one

thanks in advance experts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the foreach loop, cast each `PXResult<T0>` object in the collection to an object of the main DAC. The `PXResult<T0>` object is implicitly converted to the `T0` class. In the following sample code, records are selected from the Document table.
[To Get the Objects of the Primary DAC](https://help-2021r2.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=8609c829-7b9c-4660-acf9-891b0971b6a3)